# Is it possible to get a Vector3 from a single Input Action in Unity's Input System?

Tags: unity, input

I'm trying to implement moving up/down (R/F), left/right (A/D), forwards/backwards (W/S) all at the same time using Unity's new Input System. There is an Action type for Vector3, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding type for it.

The way movement works right now means that it would be a lot better to get the whole vector at the same time for it to work smoothly. Is there a way to do this with a single Input Action, or will I just need multiple?

[image: How I currently achieve this input.]

Comment: You can just add a function that does that to the input class using extension methods, but since you're likely to only use this code once, just create a Vector3 yourself with all the values.